# Check If Two Values Appear In The Same Row

Tags: c#, sql, rowfilter

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Management Studio. I want to check and see the two values provided by the user appear in the same row.

Something similar to this RowFilter, but in SQL instead of DataTable.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(excelTable); 
dv.RowFilter = "a = 'categoryA' AND b= 'typeA'"; 
var match = dv.Count > 0;
```

This is the way I can do in C# DataView, but I want to know if I can write a SQL query that will do the same thing in a SQL table.

ps. it doesn't matter which column the data appear in, as long as they are in the same row.

Thanks.

### EDIT

Please see my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336681/cross-index-referencing)

I'm trying to do the same thing. Instead of reading from a excel file, I will be reading directly from the database this time.

Comment: not sure I understand your problem but in SQL it's exactly the same: `where a = 'categoryA' AND b = 'typeA'`

Comment: @dkozl but when I do that, it says invalid column 'a' and 'b'. There are multiple columns in the table and I do not care which 2 columns the values appears in as long as they are on the same row

Comment: Use your database column names

Comment: @Blake like I mentioned in the post, I don't care which column the data its in, that's why I don't want to specify the column name. Say there are 5 columns in the table, I want to be able to check col[0] and col[1], or col[3] and col[5], or col[5] and col[4], and any combination. I don't want to restrict to the two specific columns